# Should we restrict to only digital communities?

Tags: discussion, scope

Our "elevator pitch" statement is:

> building, administering, managing and cultivating digital communities

Should we be limited to only *digital* communities, or can we also ask about offline (non-online?) communities as well?

Even if you don't actually have a "Moderator ♦" badge tacked on to your shirt (if you do, ... can I have one?), you can still be the leader of a group or a community. Should questions about, for example, leading a group of collaborators working together on a physical project be on-topic here?

Comment: I was curious about this too. What about something like a debate moderator?

Comment: @animuson That's an interesting topic. We can use some questions that are about more than just SE.

Comment: @animuson I think a bigger issue wrt a formal debate is that it doesn't comprise a community in the sense meant here.

Answer (score 21):

As I said on [Monica's question](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/57/127) already: I don't think we necessarily have to restrict ourselves to digital communities.

Fundamentally, the patterns and required actions are the same. Offline communities offer more options for physical rewards and punishments (and much less anonymity), of course, but the psychology is often similar.

I think, overall, a lot of these questions could easily be transferred to online communities, and as such there is no reason whatsoever for them to be off-topic. However, there may be some questions (although I can't quite figure out where they'd start) that do not fit within our expertise. We should make sure we find out where that expertise ends, and whether or not the "more offline" parts of offline communities fit in there.